# overriding of jQuery .end() method to accept parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE**
the current solution lives on this gist in case you ever need this type of functionality
https://gist.github.com/jdaly13/5581538#file-gistfile1-js

I'm trying a little experimentation where I'm trying to override jQuery's core end method with my own method that just essentially adds functionality to it

for example if you are working with jQuery you might do something like this

```
$('h1.clickme').click(function () {
     $(this).next('div').css("width", "+=200").parent().next().hide().end().end()
      //this should traverse you back to the div after the h1 clicked
})
```

I want to override the jQuery end method by adding the ability to add a number parameter 
for example

```
.end(1)
```

would do the same as

```
.end().end()
```

Here is what I have so far

```
(function(){

// Define overriding method.
jQuery.fn.end = function(no_of_times){
    var prevObject = "prevObject";
    if (!(arguments.length) || (typeof no_of_times !== "number")) {
        return this.prevObject || this.constructor(null);
    } else {
        if (no_of_times == 1) {
            return this.prevObject.prevObject || this.constructor(null)
        } else if (no_of_times == 2) {
            return this.prevObject.prevObject.prevObject || this.constructor(null)  
        } else if (no_of_times == 3) {
            return this.prevObject.prevObject.prevObject.prevObject || this.constructor(null)
        } else {
            //too many times can't type anymore
            return this.prevObject || this.constructor(null);
        }           
    }

}
})()
```

so I could call something like this

```
$('.promo-carousel').parent().prev().siblings('span').hide().end(2)
```

But obviously I don't think it's efficient to write out all those if statements
Is there an easier way to do this?  I'm sure the performance is about the same but I'm doing this more for readability sake

I thought of appending the prevObject variable with "prevObject" string based on the parameter passed something like this

```
if (!(arguments.length) || (typeof no_of_times !== "number")) {
            return this.prevObject || this.constructor(null);
        } else {
            for (i=0; i <= no_of_times; i++) {
                pObj += "prevObject."           
            }
            var prevObject = pObj.slice(0, prevObject.length -1)
            console.log(prevObject);
            return this.prevObject
        }

    }
```

But that snippet of code above didn't work
Any help is appreciated as always

Comment: Careful... I'm pretty sure `.prevObject` isn't a documented feature. Why don't you just cache the original `.end()` under a different name, and invoke it? Or better, use a different name for your custom method.

Comment: Agreed -- there's no reason to override `.end()` if a plugin and a new method will do.

Comment: yeah you are probably right - I was just thinking I'm adding functionality to it and not really overriding it so it would still work in same manner whether or not you added parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var prevObject = this.prevObject;

for(i = 1; i<no_of_times; i++) {
    prevObject = prevObject.prevObject;
    if(!prevObject) {
        prevObject = this.constructor(null);
        break
    }
}
```

Just get the `prevObject` of the `prevObject` each iteration of the loop, until `prevObject` is not found.

Comment: Thanks Elliot that worked - I knew I was missing something small meaning just storing this.prevObject in variable was the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Something similar should work.

```
var prevObject = this.prevObject;
for(i = 0; i<no_of_times; i++) {
    prevObject = prevObject.prevObject;
}
return prevObject || this.constructor(null);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - it was pretty close to Elliot's version but the readability is simpler which I always appreciate so I gave the upvote

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution : http://jsfiddle.net/QVxqY/
You don't have to reimplement any logic or keep track of the previous elements :

```
(function($){
    var originalEnd = $.fn.end;
    $.fn.end = function(n){
        if(!n)
            return originalEnd.call(this);
        return $.fn.end.call(originalEnd.call(this), n-1);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: very cool gion i wouldn't have even thought to do it that way; very nice - i cleaned up your syntax a little here http://jsfiddle.net/QVxqY/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could just reuse the old method you are overriding:

```
(function($){
    var oldfn = $.fn.end;
    $.fn.end = function(times){
        times = times || 1; // default to 1 if nothing or 0 is passed in
        var ret = this;
        for (i=0;i<times;i++) {
            ret = oldfn.call(ret);
        }
        return ret;
    };
})(jQuery);
```